# Change colors of account

Tags: entities, users

I have created a field(select list) with some colors. I want to let my site users choose the color (color of menus, blocks ...) of their account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In my example I will assume that you have a color field called **color** (machine name: **field_color**) already set to user fields `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`

By following these steps you'll be able to achieve what are you looking for.

1. Create Drupal custom module. Ref [Creating modules.](http://drupal.org/node/1074360)
2. Implement [`hook_init`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) to your custom module
3. In the `hook_init` you need to implement [`drupal_add_css`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)
4. Set HTML elements you need to let users to change; according to current user color selection.
5. The final code should look like the following:

---

```
function MODULE_NAME_init() {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);

  if(isset($account->field_color['und'])) {
    $color = $account->field_color['und'][0]['value'];

    drupal_add_css(t('#menu { background-color: #@color; }', array('@color' => $color)), array(
      'type' => 'inline',
      'media' => 'screen',
      'weight' => '10000',  
    ));
  }
}
```

**Note:** change `MODULE_NAME` to your desirable module name.

Comment: I think, if I'll use this custom module, when one of the users will choose his color, the color will change for all users, but I want that each user(my site is social network site) has his prefered color.
What do you think

Comment: its not for all users, its only for the current logged in user that has configured color.

Comment: `t()` is used to translate strings, and there is nothing to translate in a CSS style. Just use `strtr()`.